# Deleting excel data from gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a grid in my asp.net program that is supposed to insert, update and delete excel data. Here, I am facing a problem in deleting the data from the grid. Whenever i click on the 'delete' button, it generates error. The code I tried is given below.

```html
protected void RowDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      GridViewRow row = ((sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
      DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
      dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row.RowIndex);
      this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
      this.GridView1.DataBind();
      ViewState["DataTable"] = dt;
}
```

It generates error in `dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row.RowIndex);` this line.
NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. It says something like this.

Do help. And thank you for your time.

Comment: what is error ??? may be index out of bound

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Its something like this.

Comment: paste your .aspx code